# WebBrowser control not maintaining session

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, session, webbrowser-control

I'm exploring the WebBrowser control and try to login to my email account. The problem is when I open a message in a new window, it seems that the session is not carried out to the new window requiring me to login again... what's the problem of this?

Comment: Show your session code in the first page, and from the second

Comment: how exactly i'm going to do that? my email is in my WebBrowser control, but everytime I open a new window, that window is actually an instance of the default IE explorer, not my WebBrowser control...

Answer (score 2):

This [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118203/how-to-open-in-new-window-using-webbrowser-control), tells you how this is done, you need to handle the `NewWindow2` event.